# Finding a non-convex hull around regularly-spaced scatter points

Tags: python-3.x, polygon, triangulation

imagine a I have a cloud of scattered points: these points are not distributed randomly, but regular: three neighbouring points always form an equilateral triangle. The cloud of points spans up a shape which is not convex:

[image]

Now I want to find the polygon that spans the outermost points of this cloud. Convhull obviously does not work, since it would simply skip over the concave parts.

Finding the edge points is also quite simple because of this regularity:

[image]

Now here is the tricky part: Any idea on how to sort these edge points into a polygon? I considered starting with a random point, then picking a random direction and marching on, but the edge points (e.g. the northernmost tip of the cloud) give me some headache: Imagine you approach the point south-east of the northernmost tip from a south-eastern direction. Now the algorithm has two potential points where it could continue: north-west or west. North-west would obviously be the correct choice, but how could I teach the algorithm to do that?